# Error compiling Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm brand new to Haskell and have very little idea what I'm doing. I've been reading a few tutorials and am now attempting to step through a [Roll your own IRC bot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Roll_your_own_IRC_bot) example.

I get a compilation error from ghc on:

```
clean     = drop 1 . dropWhile (/= ':') . drop 1
```

The error is:

```
irc.hs:34:11: parse error on input '='
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You should post more than this small snippet (the proceeding line probably has the error).

Comment: 'Parse error on input' can signify whitespace problems... check you haven't mixed tabs and spaces. But as TomMD points out, we'd need to know more to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code you are working with, yes?

```
listen :: Handle -> IO ()
listen h = forever $ do
    t <- hGetLine h
    let s = init t
    if ping s then pong s else eval h (clean s)
    putStrLn s
  where
    forever a = a >> forever a

    clean     = drop 1 . dropWhile (/= ':') . drop 1

    ping x    = "PING :" `isPrefixOf` x
    pong x    = write h "PONG" (':' : drop 6 x)
```

Ensure your definition of `clean` is indented by the same amount as the preceeding definition of `forever`. It is on the "Roll your own IRC bot" page, but presumably isn't in the copy you're trying to compile.

Comment: If you count the characters, his '=' sign (from the code presented) could only be on column 11 (as the error indicated) if his definition is completely unindented. So it is highly likely that this is the issue.

Comment: That was the problem alright. The forever line had a 4 space indent whereas the clean line had a tab indent. I didn't even cop that haskell was sensitive to white space. Must have missed that section in my tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually fine. If you're running this in GHCi/Hugs, you're in IO, so you need a let.

```
Prelude> let clean     = drop 1 . dropWhile (/= ':') . drop 1
Prelude> :t clean
clean :: [Char] -> [Char]
Prelude>
```

Comment: I also copy-pasted his code, exactly as presented, into an otherwise empty .hs file and it compiled just fine.